# Dividing a binomial heap to 3 equal-sized binomial heaps

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

Given a binomial heap of $n$ nodes (where $n$ divides by 3), how can I split the heap to three binomial heaps with an equal number of nodes (every heap contains $n/3$ nodes).
The time complexity needs to be $O(\log n)$.

Comment: Can you edit your question and discuss what you have done/tried so far and what kind of problem are you having with your solution?

Comment: You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a hw assignment?
-hint split the linked list into two parts (N/3) +(2N/3)
then the 2N/3 to N/3 + N/3

N/3 - represent in binary so you could find out what to extract